# Suddenly, my PC cannot detect my boot device

Tags: boot

I have been using my PC for months now without any issues. But today, it suddenly froze. When I tried restarting it, the error `Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key` appeared. I tried pressing `F12` during reboot to show the available boot devices. Please see the image [boot devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkqX8.jpg) in the link for the available boot devices that show up. Normally, an "ubuntu" option referring to my boot drive would be shown there. But not, it is gone and it only shows my two other hard drives.

My system is an Ubuntu 16.04 and I have a GPU (RTX 2080), if that matters.

I tried booting from a live bootable Ubuntu and when I do `df -H`, my main boot drive is nowhere to be found.

Comment: `df` only shows mounted partitions.

Comment: Do they show up in `lsblk`/`lsblk -f` or `fdisk -l`?

Comment: is your harddrive recognized in bios/uefi?

Comment: Can you control if the hard-drive is connected to the sataport and change the cable for test?

Comment: @MaxSilvester, no they do not show in those commands.

Comment: @nobody I tried putting it in a different M.2 slot in my motherboard. Also tried reading the hard drive using an external reader. But to no avail. It looks like the ssd itself has been busted.

Comment: I am afraid it is so